# Fotorama thumbnails scrolling

Tags: gallery, thumbnails, magento2, fotorama

I am using Fotorama 4.6.4 on magento 2 and I have a problem that in some situations it does not show full selected thumbnail. For example: I selected last thumbnail and then I select previous thumnbail.

[image]

Comment: And what is your question? Do you want to post a bug report to the maintainers of that library?

Comment: I would like to know how I can fix it.

Comment: Have you tried narrowing down the bug? Is the generated markup faulty? Does the JS code to switch images work properly?

Comment: Everything works fine, but i think i found the reason. There is function onNavFrameClick in fotorama.js code. I assume that this function does wrong calculations on line "clickToShow({index: index, slow: e.altKey, user: true, coo: e._x - $nav.offset().left});".

Comment: I changed this line to "clickToShow({index: index, slow: e.altKey, user: true, coo: e._x - $nav.offset().left - 85});" and it works better (85 - width of thumbnails).